# Remove Chrome Loading Notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on a project that runs in Chrome in full-screen mode and displays data that can be edited and interacted with. It makes AJAX calls(using jQuery) frequently that cause a loading notification in the lower left-hand corner on the bottom of the screen to pop up.

These notifications are distracting when you are viewing the display and I would like to remove/prevent Chrome from displaying these loading notifications at all. Is it possible to prevent these notification by any means, or perhaps even mask the javascript that causes these notifications?

Comment: I personally do not get the loading tooltip with ajax calls. Or don't you mean that?

Comment: I think you can prevent them if you start them with a new thread, namely with setTimeout() or setInterval(). I solved my "loading" problems with them in Opera and FF...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the requests in a [web worker thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: tried this, but the notification still pops up. maybe they included requests made in a webworker as well. this is very annoying. i am trying to create a fullscreen image slideshow with a dark background and preloading images in web worker. still getting that flickering little notification each time.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a simple web page, there is no way to do so. As Dave stated, the notification is part of Google Chrome.

If it is absolutely necessary for this to not appear, you can create a Google Chrome Extension that users can install. Then, you can make the AJAX requests from the extension background page, and the status bar will not popup. However, this is not very user friendly and quite unpractical.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought so - those notifications are part of Chrome itself, not the web page. It might be possible for the user to disable the status bar, but that would be part of the browser settings rather than the page.